# Unable to reach EditorAction in EditText

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an EditText in my App where i've set in it's xml `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` and them in my fragment i'm trying to cast a function which should do stuff on Done click, but instead it has no effect and the softkeyboard doesn't even close.. in bebug the EditorActionListener is not reached when done is pressed...

Which could be the issue of it?

In my fragment the EditorActionListener looks like this:

```
private lateinit var txtQta: EditText
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        txtQta = view.findViewById(R.id.txtQta)
        txtQta.setOnEditorActionListener { _, i, _ ->
            when(i) {
                EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE -> {
                    addArticolo()
                    true
                }
            else ->
                false
            }
        }
}
```

my editText:

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtQta"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:autofillHints="qty"
            android:text="@string/_1"
            android:hint="@string/qta"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

EDIT:

Actually i had another EditorActionListener registered so for that reason it wasn't working..

Answer (score 0):

You can use also key listeners:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    //Perform Code 
                    return@OnKeyListener true
                }
                false
            })
```

maybe it will be better for you

Comment: still nothing, when i press "Done" the soft keyboard is still up and in debug it doesn't even reach the if inside KeyListener

Comment: hm... it is really strange. can you add enter test listener for getting some entering feedbacks please? I think we will need to check whether this field is available in general

Answer (score 0):

Try this with input type attribute.

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/txtQta"
             android:inputType="text"
             android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

```
txtQta.setOnEditorActionListener { _, i, _ ->
    when(i) {
        EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE -> {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"done pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EditText should have `inputType` param in xml layout, without it `setOnEditorActionListener` won't get called.

Working example.
Layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

Code:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener { _, i, _ ->
    when(i) {
        EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE -> {
            println("DONE")
        }
    }

    false
}
```

Comment: actually i have the inputType set to number|numberDecimal but anyway it's not working

Comment: I've set inputType to number|numberDecimal, copy/pasted your listener to my code, and it works. Maybe something wrong in layout or else.